# Spring JavaMailSender not sending email via server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, smtp, ubuntu-22.04

I have a project created in Tomcat 7 / jdk1.7.0_21 / Spring Framework 4.0.1. I recently reinstalled it using Tomcat 8.0.3 / openjdk1.8.0_382 on Ubuntu 22.04. Everything works fine, except the email.

I use Spring JavaMailSender to send emails using SMTP protocol. This configuration works very well through localhost:

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.office365.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>
        <property name="protocol" value="smtp"/>
        <property name="username" value="example@outlook.es"/>
        <property name="password" value="App Password"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.required">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.office365.com</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.protocols">TLSv1.2</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">1000</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preConfiguredMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
                <property name="from" value="example@outlook.es"></property>
                <property name="subject" value="Subject"></property>
    </bean>
```

But when I try it over the server the emails never arrive.

I was having trouble connecting to smtp.office365.com over IPv6. When I made changes to gai.conf file, I started getting a 220 message.

I think the 587 port is open, because I receive the 220 message and can send emails through the sSMTP program I installed to try, but even though I opened it in UFW, the 587/tcp port appears to be closed.

```
$ nmap -p 587 example.com
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
587/tcp closed submission
```

I suspect that the problem is caused by the difference between Java versions, but despite trying for a long time, I could not solve the problem.

I will be grateful if you could help me.

**EDIT:**

When I tested SMTP with telnet and openssl, Outlook and Gmail gave errors, but I was able to send email with Yandex.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.yandex.com:465 -quiet
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
verify return:1
depth=0 C = RU, ST = Moscow, L = Moscow, O = Yandex LLC, CN = smtp.yandex.ru
verify return:1
220 mail-nwsmtp-smtp-production-main-60.sas.yp-c.yandex.net (Want to use Yandex.Mail for your domain? Visit http://pdd.yandex.ru) 1702031110-APb1qDNXu0U0
EHLO example.com
250-mail-nwsmtp-smtp-production-main-60.sas.yp-c.yandex.net
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 53477376
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2
250-DSN
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
AUTH PLAIN AGluZm9AecWx0aW1zYWhkjgfjUTNvbQBkb2Jid2R1d255eWlxbWRv
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful. 1702031132-APb1qDNXu0U0
MAIL FROM: info@example.com
250 2.1.0 <info@example.com> ok 1702031142-APb1qDNXu0U0-mV4GqJPK
RCPT TO: info@example.com
250 2.1.5 <info@example.com> recipient ok 1702031152-APb1qDNXu0U0-mV4GqJPK
DATA
354 Start mail input, end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
From: info@example.com
To: info@example.com
Subject: Email client recommendation
I'm currently using openssl to send emails. Do you know if there are any good desktop applications that can send emails?
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on mail-nwsmtp-smtp-production-main-60.sas.yp-c.yandex.net 1702031214-APp1qKnXu0U0-mV4GcJPK
```

So I changed the JavaMailSender configuration as follows, but it still doesn't work.

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.yandex.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="465"/>
        <property name="username" value="info@example.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="App Password"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms">LOGIN PLAIN</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.yandex.com</prop>
                <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preConfiguredMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">     
                <property name="from" value="info@example.com"></property>
                <property name="subject" value="Subject"></property>
    </bean>
```

Where am I making a mistake?

**SOLUTION:**

Updating the JavaMail (mail.jar) fixed the problem. Its older versions only support TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: Are you able to answer you own question and accept it? This seems like a good question and answer for anyone having this specific problem.